# How important is the point of view in Cucumber steps?

Tags: cucumber

I was wondering if cucumber steps would better serve the reader for being written in third person than first person when describing a non-human agent. I felt that fewer pronouns cleared up who was doing what.

```
Scenario: Monitor notifies admin for healthcheck failure.
  Given I am a monitor
  When I retrieve a failed healthcheck message
  Then I notifies the admin

Scenario: Monitor notifies admin for healthcheck failure.
  Given there is a monitor
  When the monitor retrieves a failed healthcheck message
  Then the monitor notifies the admin
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make any difference at all. =p

```
Scenario: Monitor notifies admin of healthcheck failure.
  Given I am a monitor
  When I retrieve a failed healthcheck message
  Then I should notify an admin

Scenario: Monitor notifies admin for healthcheck failure.
  Given there is a monitor
  When it retrieves a failed healthcheck message
  Then it should notify an admin
```

It's just the way you like to write it. =p